# Improve performance in Oracle on a SELECT FROM VIEW

Tags: oracle, query-performance

I have created a View in Oracle with this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW MERGE_VIEW
AS
(
   SELECT *
   FROM V_OLD_DATA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *
   FROM V_NEW_DATA
);
```

Where `V_OLD_DATA` is a Materialized View, refreshed once per day and `V_NEW_DATA` is a View created using a lot of `UNION ALL`. They have also the same attributes.
The problem is that the performance are bad (~ 1.35s) when I am selecting as in the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MERGE_VIEW;
```

and I need this time to be something less than 1 second at most. 
Surprisingly, if I try to execute the following code instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM V_OLD_DATA
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM V_NEW_DATA;
```

It is taking ~ 0.45s at most. How is this time lag possible?
I tried to push external conditions in V_NEW_DATA inside each `WHERE` clause of the unions and I am also using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45399140/improve-performance-select-union-command-mysql) other query but it won't get better.
Do you have any other general suggestion to improve the performance?